# Adding a fixed footer to 1400dp long layout

Tags: android

I have a very long layout to design and I have design it and used ScrollView, basically it is 1400dp long layout. I'm using this in my activity. I want to implement a fixed footer in my activity even thought scrolled the UI I want to footer to be fixed in the screen.

this is the layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1400dp"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried to add the footer (textview ) to the bottom and then it gets hide when scrolled. Then I tried to limit the ScrollView, layout_height to 400dp and tried then it gives a white space below but it doesn't allow to add anything there. 
SO my problem is, is it possible to add a fix footer in android layout.

[image]

Comment: Just wrap your ScrollView in a LinearLayout and place your footer at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the Scrollview in a RelativeLayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1400dp"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <YourFooter
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    ...        
    </YourFooter>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Wrap the `ScrollView` in a vertical `LinearLayout`, whose height and width are both set to `match_parent`.

Step #2: Set the height of the `ScrollView` to `0dip` and set the weight to `1`.

Step #3: Add your fixed footer after the `ScrollView` in the `LinearLayout`, setting the height to be whatever makes sense (e.g., `wrap_content`).

Now, the footer will be given its space at the bottom of the `LinearLayout`, and the rest of the space will be given over to the `ScrollView`.

Comment: I got the error which is shown in my updated question (screen shot), why is that?

Comment: @modabeckham: Among possibly other problems, you did not make the `LinearLayout` vertical. You put an `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute on the `ScrollView`, not the `LinearLayout`. That being said, the `RelativeLayout` approach from the other answer works as well. As the Perl people like to say, "there's more than one way to do it". :-)

Comment: yes of course, thanks for your detailed answer. Everyday I'm learning new things. I really appreciate your answer. Cheers